# Need of New keyword in multilevel inheritance c#

Tags: c#-4.0

Hello this question is regarding when exactly New keyword i;e Method hiding in base class can be done.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.calculatebnft();
        a = new B();
        a.calculatebnft();
        a = new C();
        a.calculatebnft();
        a = new Program();
        a.calculatebnft();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public new string calculatebnft()
    {
        string bnft = "";
        Console.WriteLine("SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS");
        return bnft;
    }
}
class A
{
    //my code here
    public virtual string calculatebnft()
    {
        string bnft = "";
        Console.WriteLine("A");//my code here
        return bnft;
    }
}

class B : A
{
    //my code here
    public override string calculatebnft()
    {
        string bnft = "";
        Console.WriteLine("B");//my code here
        return bnft;
    }
}

class C : B
{
    public new string calculatebnft()
    {
        string bnft = "";
        Console.WriteLine("C");
        return bnft;
    }
}
```

When above program is executed output is

A
B
B
B

in this case New Keyword in class C not hiding method in class B? what is the reason behind it.

Sorry am new to .Net and if my question is too basic

Comment: Yes, it's hiding the method from class B. What makes you think it isn't? If you were expecting the method to be called after `a = new C();`, the point is that the method is *hiding* the method originally declared in `A`; it's not *overriding* it. If you had `C c = new C(); c.calculatebnft();` then that would call the new method.

Comment: I was thinking New will hide Method in class B.

Comment: And it does. It doesn't override it though. It sounds like you should research the difference between hiding and overriding.